# How to use bit manipulation to find 5th bit, and to return number of 1 bits in an integer

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

Assume Z is an unsigned integer. Using ~, <<, >>, &, | , +, and - provide statements which return the desired result.

I am allowed to introduce new binary values if needed.

I have these problems:

1.Extract the 5th bit from *the left* Z.

For this I was thinking about doing something like

```
  x x x x x x x x 
& 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 
___________________

  0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
```

Does this make sense for extracting the fifth bit? I am not totally sure how I would make this work by using just Z when I do not know its values. (I am relatively new to all of this). Would this type of idea work though?

2.Return the number of 1 bits in Z

```
Here I kind of have no idea how to work this out. What I really need to know is how to work on just Z with the operators, but I m not sure exactly how to.
```

Like I said I am new to this, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/2185719/1151831

Comment: 5th bit - best to detail are you starting from the MSBit or LSBit - starting from 0 or 1?

Comment: There is a good reason to start counting on the right: it also works for bitstrings that happen to be larger. Or infinite.

Answer (score 1):

## Problem 1

You’re right on the money.  I’d do an `&` and a `>>` so that you get either a nice 0 or 1.

```
result = (z & 0x08) >> 3;
```

However, this may not be strictly necessary.  For example, if you’re trying to check whether the bit is set as part of an `if` conditional, you can exploit C’s definition of anything nonzero as true.

```
if (z & 0x08)
        do_stuff();
```

## Problem 2

There are [a whole variety of ways](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetNaive) to do this.  According to that page, the following methodology dates from 1960, though it wasn’t published in C until 1988.

```
for (result = 0; z; result++)
        z &= z - 1;
```

Exactly why this works might not be obvious at first, but if you work through a few examples, you’ll quickly see why it does.

It’s worth noting that this operation – determining the number of 1 bits in a number – is sufficiently important to have a name (population count or [Hamming weight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight)) and, on recent Intel and AMD processors, a [dedicated instruction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSE4#POPCNT_and_LZCNT).  If you’re using GCC, you can use the `__builtin_popcount` intrinsic.

Answer (score 0):

Problem 1 looks right, except you should finish it by shifting the result right by 4 to get that bit after the mask.

To implement the mask, you need to know what integer is represented by a single 5th bit. That number is incidentally 2^5 = 32. So you can just AND z with 32 and shift it right by 4.

Problem 2:

```
int answer = 0;
while (z != 0){  //stop when there are no more 1 bits in z

   //the following masks the lowest bit in z and adds it into answer
   //if z ends with a 0, nothing is added, otherwise 1 is added
   answer += (z & 1);
   //this shifts z right by 1 to get the next higher bit
   z >>= 1;
}
return answer;
```

Comment: Thank you. How would I do something similar on Z for the first question? And also could you explain why you do all of that in the while loop?

Answer (score 0):

To find out the value of the fifth bit, you don't care about the bottom bits so you can get rid of them:

```
unsigned int answer = z >> 4;
```

The fifth bit becomes the bottom bit, so you can strip it off with a bitwise-AND:

```
answer = answer & 1;
```

To find the number of 1-bits in a number you can apply stakSmashr's solution. You could optimise this further if you know you need to count the number of bits in a lot of integers - precompute the number of bits in every possible 8-bit number and store it in a table. There will only be 256 entries in the table so it won't use much memory. Then, you can loop over your data one byte at a time and find the answer from the table. This lookup will be quicker than looping again over each bit.